# How to find value(s) in row in pandas after filtering out certain data, and then applying a custom sort?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a df with 8 currencies (CAD, AUD, NOK, SEK, NZD, EUR, GBP, JPY) and 2 different data points: 12M PR (12 month price return) and 12M ZS (12 month z-score).

```
df = {'Date': ('2015-10-6', '2015-10-7'),
      'CAD 12M PR': (-7.4, -4.9),
      'AUD 12M PR': (-2.3, -1.6),
      'NOK 12M PR': (2.6, 6.4),
      'SEK 12M PR': (6.7, 8.6),
      'NZD 12M PR': (3.1, 2.9),
      'EUR 12M PR': (2.2, 4.7),
      'GBP 12M PR': (-3.6, -2.5),
      'JPY 12M PR': (13.8, 15.7),
      'CAD 12M ZS': (3.1, 2.5),
      'AUD 12M ZS': (-1.7, 3.0),
      'NOK 12M ZS': (2.0, 1.8),
      'SEK 12M ZS': (2.6, 2.6),
      'NZD 12M ZS': (-4.5, -5.6),
      'EUR 12M ZS': (-3.8, -3.7),
      'GBP 12M ZS': (-1.6, -2.7),
      'JPY 12M ZS': (3.0, 2.1)
     }
```

I want to first apply a filter by retrieving the lowest 4 currencies by 12M PR along with those currencies respective 12M ZS. After the first filter, df2 should look like below:

```
df2 = {'Date': ('2015-10-6', '2015-10-7'),
      'CAD 12M PR': (-7.4, -4.9),
      'AUD 12M PR': (-2.3, -1.6),
      'EUR 12M PR': (2.2, 4.7),
      'GBP 12M PR': (-3.6, -2.5),
      'CAD 12M ZS': (3.1, 2.5),
      'AUD 12M ZS': (-1.7, 3.0),
      'EUR 12M ZS': (-3.8, -3.7),
      'GBP 12M ZS': (-1.6, -2.7),
     }
```

After the filter has been applied, I want to retrieve the 2 currencies (from list that's been filtered) that have the lowest 12M ZS. Of the filtered list above, AUD and EUR have the lowest 12M ZS for both dates (but this could change). After this sort by 12M ZS, df3 should look like below:

```
df3 = {'Date': ('2015-10-6', '2015-10-7'),
      'AUD 12M PR': (-2.3, -1.6),
      'EUR 12M PR': (2.2, 4.7),
      'AUD 12M ZS': (-1.7, 3.0),
      'EUR 12M ZS': (-3.8, -3.7),
     }
```

So the first filter finds the 4 currencies with the lowest 12M PR, and the 2nd sort finds the 2 currencies with the lowest 12M ZS of the 4 currencies with the lowest 12M PR. But I don't know how to go from df to df3.

I can get the 4 currencies with the lowest 12M PR (df2) using the below code:

```
Short = {
              'Short 1':
             df[['CAD 12M PR', 'AUD 12M PR', 'NOK 12M PR', 'SEK 12M PR', 'NZD 12M PR', 'EUR 12M PR', 'GBP 12M PR', 'JPY 12M PR']].T.apply(lambda x: x.nsmallest(1).idxmax()).str[0:3],
             'Short 2':
             df[['CAD 12M PR', 'AUD 12M PR', 'NOK 12M PR', 'SEK 12M PR', 'NZD 12M PR', 'EUR 12M PR', 'GBP 12M PR', 'JPY 12M PR']].T.apply(lambda x: x.nsmallest(2).idxmax()).str[0:3],
             'Short 3':
             df[['CAD 12M PR', 'AUD 12M PR', 'NOK 12M PR', 'SEK 12M PR', 'NZD 12M PR', 'EUR 12M PR', 'GBP 12M PR', 'JPY 12M PR']].T.apply(lambda x: x.nsmallest(3).idxmax()).str[0:3],
             'Short 4':
             df[['CAD 12M PR', 'AUD 12M PR', 'NOK 12M PR', 'SEK 12M PR', 'NZD 12M PR', 'EUR 12M PR', 'GBP 12M PR', 'JPY 12M PR']].T.apply(lambda x: x.nsmallest(4).idxmax()).str[0:3],
             'Short 1 12M PR':
             df[['CAD 12M PR', 'AUD 12M PR', 'NOK 12M PR', 'SEK 12M PR', 'NZD 12M PR', 'EUR 12M PR', 'GBP 12M PR', 'JPY 12M PR']].apply(lambda row: row.nsmallest(1).values[-1],axis=1),
             'Short 2 12M PR':
             df[['CAD 12M PR', 'AUD 12M PR', 'NOK 12M PR', 'SEK 12M PR', 'NZD 12M PR', 'EUR 12M PR', 'GBP 12M PR', 'JPY 12M PR']].apply(lambda row: row.nsmallest(2).values[-1],axis=1),
             'Short 3 12M PR':
             df[['CAD 12M PR', 'AUD 12M PR', 'NOK 12M PR', 'SEK 12M PR', 'NZD 12M PR', 'EUR 12M PR', 'GBP 12M PR', 'JPY 12M PR']].apply(lambda row: row.nsmallest(3).values[-1],axis=1),
             'Short 4 12M PR':
             df[['CAD 12M PR', 'AUD 12M PR', 'NOK 12M PR', 'SEK 12M PR', 'NZD 12M PR', 'EUR 12M PR', 'GBP 12M PR', 'JPY 12M PR']].apply(lambda row: row.nsmallest(4).values[-1],axis=1),
                }
```

Once I have the 4 currencies with the lowest 12M PR (df2), I don't know how to apply the last sort based on the filtered list (df2) to arrive at df3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution, although perhaps not the most efficient solution.

```
import pandas as pd


df = {
    "Date": ("2015-10-6", "2015-10-7"),
    "CAD 12M PR": (-7.4, -4.9),
    "AUD 12M PR": (-2.3, -1.6),
    "NOK 12M PR": (2.6, 6.4),
    "SEK 12M PR": (6.7, 8.6),
    "NZD 12M PR": (3.1, 2.9),
    "EUR 12M PR": (2.2, 4.7),
    "GBP 12M PR": (-3.6, -2.5),
    "JPY 12M PR": (13.8, 15.7),
    "CAD 12M ZS": (3.1, 2.5),
    "AUD 12M ZS": (-1.7, 3.0),
    "NOK 12M ZS": (2.0, 1.8),
    "SEK 12M ZS": (2.6, 2.6),
    "NZD 12M ZS": (-4.5, -5.6),
    "EUR 12M ZS": (-3.8, -3.7),
    "GBP 12M ZS": (-1.6, -2.7),
    "JPY 12M ZS": (3.0, 2.1),
}

df2 = {
    "Date": ("2015-10-6", "2015-10-7"),
    "CAD 12M PR": (-7.4, -4.9),
    "AUD 12M PR": (-2.3, -1.6),
    "EUR 12M PR": (2.2, 4.7),
    "GBP 12M PR": (-3.6, -2.5),
    "CAD 12M ZS": (3.1, 2.5),
    "AUD 12M ZS": (-1.7, 3.0),
    "EUR 12M ZS": (-3.8, -3.7),
    "GBP 12M ZS": (-1.6, -2.7),
}


df3 = {
    "Date": ("2015-10-6", "2015-10-7"),
    "AUD 12M PR": (-2.3, -1.6),
    "EUR 12M PR": (2.2, 4.7),
    "AUD 12M ZS": (-1.7, 3.0),
    "EUR 12M ZS": (-3.8, -3.7),
}

pd_df = pd.DataFrame(df)

# setup
n_PR = 4
n_ZS = 2
target_date = "2015-10-6"

# only look at target date data for now
pd_target_date = pd_df.loc[pd_df["Date"] == target_date]

# separate 12M PR and 12M ZS
pd_PR_df = pd_target_date.filter(regex=".*12M PR")
pd_ZS_df = pd_target_date.filter(regex=".*12M ZS")

# get the smallest n values for PR and ZS
pd_PR_df = pd_PR_df.transpose().nsmallest(n=n_PR, columns=0).transpose()

# get the country names of those that passed the first filter
# 3 is hard coded for 3-letter symbol for currency
lowest_countries = [x[:3] for x in pd_PR_df.columns]

# get the lowest countries' ZS
regex_str = "(" + ".*|".join(lowest_countries) + ".*)"
pd_ZS_df = pd_ZS_df.filter(regex=regex_str)

# aggregate results back to original data frame and sanity check
pd_df2_test = pd_df[pd_PR_df.columns].join(pd_df[pd_ZS_df.columns], how="outer")
pd_df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2)
pd_df2 = pd_df2.drop(columns=["Date"])
# absurd assert to make sure they match, this was significnatly more complicated than it should have been, there is probably a better way
assert set(pd_df2_test.columns) == set(pd_df2.columns) and all(
    [
        len(pd_df2[pd_df2[col] == pd_df2_test[col]]) == len(pd_df2[col])
        for col in pd_df2.columns
    ]
), "DataFrames did not match"


# second filter
pd_ZS_df = pd_ZS_df.transpose().nsmallest(n=n_ZS, columns=0).transpose()

lowest_countries = [x[:3] for x in pd_ZS_df.columns]

# get the lowest countries' PR
regex_str = "(" + ".*|".join(lowest_countries) + ".*)"
pd_PR_df = pd_PR_df.filter(regex=regex_str)

# aggregate results back to original data frame and sanity check
pd_df3_test = pd_df[pd_PR_df.columns].join(pd_df[pd_ZS_df.columns], how="outer")
pd_df3 = pd.DataFrame(df3)
pd_df3 = pd_df3.drop(columns=["Date"])
# absurd assert to make sure they match, this was significnatly more complicated than it should have been, there is probably a better way
assert set(pd_df3_test.columns) == set(pd_df3.columns) and all(
    [
        len(pd_df3[pd_df3[col] == pd_df3_test[col]]) == len(pd_df3[col])
        for col in pd_df3.columns
    ]
), "DataFrames did not match"

final_result = pd_df3_test
print(final_result)
```

Comment: you are a hero, sir

Answer (score 0):

Below is another way to solve the problem by re-formatting the data. This was sent from a user on Quantopian (much thanks to him and everyone who helped).

```
#First import pandas because we'll probably need it
import pandas as pd
# The initial data is in the form of a dict
df = {'Date': ('2015-10-6', '2015-10-7'),
      'CAD 12M PR': (-7.4, -4.9),
      'AUD 12M PR': (-2.3, -1.6),
      'NOK 12M PR': (2.6, 6.4),
      'SEK 12M PR': (6.7, 8.6),
      'NZD 12M PR': (3.1, 2.9),
      'EUR 12M PR': (2.2, 4.7),
      'GBP 12M PR': (-3.6, -2.5),
      'JPY 12M PR': (13.8, 15.7),
      'CAD 12M ZS': (3.1, 2.5),
      'AUD 12M ZS': (-1.7, 3.0),
      'NOK 12M ZS': (2.0, 1.8),
      'SEK 12M ZS': (2.6, 2.6),
      'NZD 12M ZS': (-4.5, -5.6),
      'EUR 12M ZS': (-3.8, -3.7),
      'GBP 12M ZS': (-1.6, -2.7),
      'JPY 12M ZS': (3.0, 2.1)
     }

# Turn the dict into a dataframe
pd_df = pd.DataFrame(df)

# Set the index to be the date (for now)
pd_df_by_date = pd_df.set_index('Date')
pd_df_by_date

# Stack the dataframe to make columns into rows. Rows are easier to work with.
pd_df_stacked_multi_index = pd_df_by_date.stack()

# Let's remove the multi-index which stack created. It's probably easier without it
pd_df_stacked_single_index = pd_df_stacked_multi_index.reset_index()

# Name the columns for easier reading
pd_df_stacked_single_index.columns = ['date', 'full_desc', 'data']

# We really want to group and sort and select by country, PR, and ZS
# Best way to do that is to make those into separate columns
pd_df_stacked_single_index['country'] = pd_df_stacked_single_index.full_desc.str[:3]
pd_df_stacked_single_index['field'] = pd_df_stacked_single_index.full_desc.str[-2:]

   # First let's delete the full_desc column since it's not really needed anymore
pd_df_no_full_desc = pd_df_stacked_single_index.drop('full_desc', axis=1)

# Sort of what we want but really want index as date and country and then two columns for PR adn ZS
# Let's start with getting the index correct (add field because we want to use it later to unstack)
pd_df_indexed = pd_df_no_full_desc.set_index(['date', 'country', 'field'])

# Now turn the field into two columns using unstack
pd_df_indexed_unstacked = pd_df_indexed.unstack('field')

# Soooo close. Let's remove the hierarchical columns. Those were added when we unstacked.
pd_df_indexed_unstacked.columns = pd_df_indexed_unstacked.columns.droplevel()

# Finally remove the multi-index just to make things easier
df_clean = pd_df_indexed_unstacked.reset_index()

# Now we can get down to business...
# Find the 4 smallest PR by date (one could also do this using the apply method)
# Drop level 0 of the index which get's added when we do a group_by
# Use the df names in the original post
indexes_of_smallest_4_pr = df_clean.groupby('date').PR.nsmallest(4).index.droplevel(0)

df2 = df_clean.loc[indexes_of_smallest_4_pr]

# In a similar way get the 2 smallest by ZS
indexes_of_smallest_2_zs = df2.groupby('date').ZS.nsmallest(2).index.droplevel(0)

df3 = df2.loc[indexes_of_smallest_2_zs]

#That's it We have our two dataframes df2 and df3.

#Looking back at what was done the majority of effort was getting the dataframes into a format which was easier to work with. If the original data was in a better format then everything could have been done with a couple of lines of code.

# Let's create a cleaner dataframe to start with
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['date', 'country', 'PR', 'ZS'],
             data=
             [['2015-10-6', 'AUD', -2.3, -1.7],
              ['2015-10-6', 'CAD', -7.4, 3.1],
              ['2015-10-6', 'EUR', 2.2, -3.8],
              ['2015-10-6', 'GBP', -3.6, -1.6],
              ['2015-10-6', 'JPY', 13.8, 3.0],
              ['2015-10-6', 'NOK', 2.6, 2.0],
              ['2015-10-6', 'NZD', 3.1, -4.5],
              ['2015-10-6', 'SEK', 6.7, 2.6],
              ['2015-10-7', 'AUD', -1.6, 3.0],
              ['2015-10-7', 'CAD', -4.9, 2.5],
              ['2015-10-7', 'EUR', 4.7, -3.7],
              ['2015-10-7', 'GBP', -2.5, -2.7],
              ['2015-10-7', 'JPY', 15.7, 2.1],
              ['2015-10-7', 'NOK', 6.4, 1.8],
              ['2015-10-7', 'NZD', 2.9, -5.6],
              ['2015-10-7', 'SEK', 8.6, 2.6]
             ], 
             )
df.head(5)
date    country PR  ZS
0   2015-10-6   AUD -2.3    -1.7
1   2015-10-6   CAD -7.4    3.1
2   2015-10-6   EUR 2.2 -3.8
3   2015-10-6   GBP -3.6    -1.6
4   2015-10-6   JPY 13.8    3.0
# Find the 4 smallest PR by date
df2 = df.loc[df.groupby('date').PR.nsmallest(4).index.droplevel(0)]
df2
date    country PR  ZS
1   2015-10-6   CAD -7.4    3.1
3   2015-10-6   GBP -3.6    -1.6
0   2015-10-6   AUD -2.3    -1.7
2   2015-10-6   EUR 2.2 -3.8
9   2015-10-7   CAD -4.9    2.5
11  2015-10-7   GBP -2.5    -2.7
8   2015-10-7   AUD -1.6    3.0
14  2015-10-7   NZD 2.9 -5.6
# Find the 2 smallest ZS by date
df3 = df2.loc[df2.groupby('date').ZS.nsmallest(2).index.droplevel(0)]
df3
```